# Is there an Edit mode for table - like iOS - in Android

Tags: android, android-layout

I wonder if Android have an "edit mode" for table like the [one provided in iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html), that allows you to mark each row in a table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked up how iOS offers add/delete buttons to their table-views, and it would be pretty straightforward to implement the same UI functionality in Android using a custom/compound widget.

For dynamic tabular layouts, I'd suggest using some view backed by a [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) (for lists or grids/tables) or [ExpandableListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListAdapter.html) (for trees/collapsible lists). You can create a custom widget or layout that combines a pair of add/delete buttons with your View of choice. Then have the buttons' actions connect to add/delete item functions on your Adapter.

This approach gives you the opportunity to confirm and/or verify changes to both the View and to the underlying data, and you can reuse the widget for different combinations of View/Adapter/data source.

I would avoid trying to use TableLayout/TableRow structures for data-display in general, as they are better for static entities and you're looking for something that will automatically adjust to the user's changes.

EDIT: Here are links to building compound widgets and to [working with ListViews & ListAdapters](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html).

Android documentation website: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html#compound

Short blog post: http://www.workreloaded.com/2011/02/composite-component/

Search here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+compound+component&submit=search

Comment: Thanks ... do you know any link to such example?

Comment: I found this link, would this be inline with what you explained above: http://appfulcrum.com/2011/09/21/listview-example-5-using-sqlite-database/

Comment: The blog you linked to has the right idea, but it doesn't seem that clear to follow if you're learning. I'd recommend the Vogella tutorials (added to answer above).